# Python Scrapy - How to reset the connection mid crawl?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy on python 3, and the website I'm crawling disallowed log in via spiders on their robots.txt file. Also after some number of request (32) they start blocking the data I want to access, demanding log in.

I need to crawl several thousand pages, so I was wondering if there is a way in scrappy to stop the crawl after some number of pages, drop the connection, wait a couple of seconds and reconnect. If not, then whats the best way to handle the situation I am?

Comment: you can set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in settings.py file

Comment: That's kinda like the last resource I want to try. I would rather respect the robots.txt file. I tried  "COOKIES_ENABLED=False" in the settings.py file and so far seems to be working.

Comment: Then you can try to randomly assign user_agent from a pool of user_agent

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: Try to rotate IPs and also the user-agent string for different requests

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to avoid robots.txt - Technically, you can set

> ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

in Settings.py. However, unsure about whether it would be good option legally.

Regarding the interval in crawling - If you can share piece of code then it'll be helpful. Also if you're using any loop then there will be an option.

Crawler is the backend process and one type of scrapping itself, so one of the thumb rule will be respecting the site on which your crawler is. As sometime it affects to performance of the website too. You should check this link for more details - https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/